# Python Print Displays

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a problem with this project that I'm working. My problem that I am having is that at the end of my Display list I am getting a negative number, so I wondering if someone could give me any direction on how to fix this problem? I need it to be zero.

```
InitalPrice = float(input("Enter the Price of the Computer: "))
Month = 0
DownPayment = InitalPrice * .10
Balance = (InitalPrice - DownPayment)
AnInterest = Balance * .01 / 12
MonthlyPayment = Balance * 0.05 

print("%0s%20s%20s%20s%13s%23s" %("Month", "Current Balance", "Interest 
Owed", "Principal Owed", "Payment", "Balance Remaining"))


for i in range(1, 100): 
    #AnInterest = AnInterest
    if Balance >= 0:
        InitalPrice = InitalPrice - InitalPrice * .10 

        Principal = MonthlyPayment - AnInterest
        Balance = Balance + AnInterest - MonthlyPayment
        print("%0d%20.2f%20.3f%20.2f%13.2f%23.2f" %(i, InitalPrice, AnInterest, Principal, MonthlyPayment, Balance))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting a constant amount as the MonthlyPayment (ie. 10% of your balance). If the balance plus the interest is less then that MonthlyPayment then the balance becomes negative. You just have to do a simple check to see that this is not the case.

P.S. I would recommend just using a while loop for this problem as the for loop can either iterate too many times, or not enough times.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much.